# Sort array in JS which contsist of another date arrays by first value

Tags: javascript, date, sorting

How I can sort an array by the first value. Below is the array example

```
[
    [
        14th Aug,
        8th Aug,
    ],
    [
        8th Aug,
        22th Aug,
    ],
    [
        6th Aug,
        14th Aug,
    ] 
]
```

As result, I need to get a new array such as

```
[
   [
        6th Aug,
        14th Aug,
    ],
    [
        8th Aug,
        22th Aug,
    ],
    [
        14th Aug,
        8th Aug,
    ] 
]
```

So only the first value must be taken into account for sorting

Comment: Are the values of your array arrays of strings or arrays of Dates?

Comment: Can you please add another month to your sample and result (if applicable)? Could there be different years as well?

Comment: Values are JS Objects

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?  The same logic in [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979256/328193) (or any example of custom sort logic in JavaScript) applies here.  The only difference is that your "objects" being sorted are also arrays.  But the overall logic is the same.  Pass a custom comparer function to the sort operation.  Can you show your attempt and demonstrate in what way it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @Ollie: JS Objects could be (among others) of class `Date` and class `String`. So what do you have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)